# Page break workaround (javascript) for chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, printing, page-break

So, as known, this awesome CSS properties:

```
  table { page-break-inside:auto }
  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

Doesnt work on Chrome. So now comes the workaround. I have this table structure (please note JSP and EL syntax)

```
    <table class="table resultTable">
        <thead class="repeat">
            <tr class="head">
                <th>XPTO HEADER</th>
                <th>XPTO HEADER</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${items}" var="t" varStatus="loop">
                <tr>                        
                    <td class="money">${t.XPTO}</td>
                    <td class="money">${t.XPTO2}</td>
                </tr>
                <c:if test="${(loop.index + 1) % 20 == 0}">
                    <tr class="break-page">
                    </tr>                   
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>                                        
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Two things to notice: **the class "repeat" on the thread** and  **the empty tr with break-page class after 20 rows**.

So, check this CSS:

```
    @media print {          
        .break-page {
             display: block; page-break-before: always;
        }
    }
```

And check this JS:

```
     var repeat = $('.repeat tr');

     $('.break-page').after(repeat.clone());
```

That's awesome :) This produces exactly what I want. Check how this first page:

[image]

And the second page, you can see that the header repeats, but, check out this huge white space:

[image]

So that's it. Can you guys help me get rid of that huge white space?
Also I hope this helps if someone is having the same trouble as I am.

Thank you

Comment: I assume you are seeing this in Google's print preview. Right click and inspect element and look through to see if you determine what is causing the issue. My guess is that the second page table (in reality) is starting exactly where your first one broke.

Comment: Yes Kevin I am. Although I couldn´t inspect element on the print preview. All I get from chrome is: 

```<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="chrome://print/85/0/print.pdf" stream-url="chrome://print/85/0/print.pdf" headers="">``` PS: I think you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was: used div instead of table tag. Also I inserted a page-break after 20 rows for chrome. Created a javascript hack to add the header again.

**NOTE:** this creates different pages and data layout for each browser. Chrome has 3 pages and the last one the table is kinda in the middle... And firefox has only two pages, that fits perfectly. That was the best I could do.

HTML

```
            <div class="divTable">
                <div class="divHeading">
                    <div class="divCell">${i18n.label.initialValue}</div>
                    <div class="divCell">${i18n.label.additions}</div>
                    <div class="divCell">${i18n.label.discounts}</div>
                    <div class="divCell">${i18n.label.finalValue}</div>
                </div>
                <c:forEach items="${detailedCashFlow.transactions}" var="t" varStatus="loop">
                        <div class="divCell money">${t.initialValue}</div>
                        <div class="divCell money">${t.totalAddition}</div>
                        <div class="divCell money">${t.totalDiscount}</div>
                        <div class="divCell money">${t.value}</div>
                    </div>

                    //THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT
                    <c:if test="${fn:length(detailedCashFlow.transactions) > (loop.index + 1 ) && (loop.index + 1) % 20 == 0}">
                        <div class="break-page"></div>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>                                        
            </div>
```

CSS

```
            .divTable
            {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
            .divTitle
            {
                display: table-caption;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: larger;
            }
            .divHeading
            {
                display: table-row;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center; 
            }
            .divRow
            {
                display: table-row;
            }
            .divCell
            {
                display: table-cell;
                border: solid;
                border-width: thin;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
                text-align: center;         
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .divRow:nth-child(even){
                background: #aad4ff !important;
            }
            .divRow:nth-child(odd){
                background: #FFF !important;
            }

            @media print {                        
                .divHeading { 
                    display:table-header-group;
                }

                .divRow
                {
                    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
                    webkit-page-break-inside:avoid; 
                    page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;    
                }

                .break-page {
                    page-break-before: always;
                }
            }
```

JS HACK

```
     var is_chrome = window.chrome;

     if(is_chrome){
         var repeat = $('.divHeading');

         $('.break-page').after(repeat.clone());             
     }
```